# Providing Key Usage to X509Certificate generated with Java BouncyCastle

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, digital-certificate

Here is my piece of code to for generating `X509Certificate` with **BouncyCastle** API

```
private static X509Certificate createCertificate(String dn, String issuer,
        PublicKey publicKey, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
    X509V3CertificateGenerator certGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
    certGenerator.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(new Random()
            .nextLong())));
    certGenerator.setIssuerDN(new X509Name(dn));
    certGenerator.setSubjectDN(new X509Name(dn));
    certGenerator.setIssuerDN(new X509Name(issuer)); // Set issuer!
    certGenerator.setNotBefore(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    certGenerator.setNotAfter(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    certGenerator.setPublicKey(publicKey);
    certGenerator.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WithRSAEncryption");
    **certGenerator..... ??? what for  key usage ?** 
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certGenerator.generate(
            privateKey, "BC");
    return certificate;
}
```

[Full code you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397131/generating-x509certificate-with-bouncycastle-with-java)

My question is there is no way to set the key usage for the generated Digital Certificate.

I am trying to set the usage as **Encryption.**. There is no such method/way in `X509V3CertificateGenerator`  class.

How to go about it.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You want to set KeyUsage or ExtendedKeyUsage usage attributes? In any case, look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884995/error-while-creating-x-509-certificate

Comment: @user1516873 Thanks for the link, I remember you. seen many posts regarding certificates .Time to give some name to your profile :). keep up.

Comment: What part of your guestion is not answered by this [Bouncy Castle documentation](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation#X.509PublicKeyCertificateandCertificationRequestGeneration-ExtendedKeyUsage) and onwards?